# Vibrate when a item starts playing AVQueuePlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I have an AVQueuePlayer in which I add some items during runtime.

```
NSArray *queue = [self.queuePlayer items];
if ([self.queuePlayer canInsertItem:sound afterItem:[queue lastObject]]) [self.queuePlayer insertItem:sound afterItem:[queue lastObject]];
```

No item is added when the AVQueuePlayer is initialized. All I do is an alloc init. I also send a play message as soon as they view load, that way when a new item is added it starts playing right away.

I am trying to make the phone vibrates as soon as a new item starts playing.

I was checking the online documentation and the only interesting thing I found was a notification that is sent when the item did play to end.

```
AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
```

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AVPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer):

> You can observe the status of a player using key-value observing.

Some additional details:

> So that you can add and remove observers safely, AVPlayer serializes notifications of changes that occur dynamically during playback on a dispatch queue. By default, this queue is the main queue (see dispatch_get_main_queue). To ensure safe access to a player’s nonatomic properties while dynamic changes in playback state may be reported, you must serialize access with the receiver’s notification queue. In the common case, such serialization is naturally achieved by invoking AVPlayer’s various methods on the main thread or queue.

Here's a simple example.  When you create the player, sign up to be notified of status changes:

```
[self.queuePlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:kNilOptions context:nil];
```

Then, add this method, which will get called when the `queuePlayer`'s `status` changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self.queuePlayer && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (self.queuePlayer.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
        } 
    }
}
```

(I'm not sure the exact vibration behavior you want, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.)

Comment: The problem is that ReadyToPlay means the buffering is completed, not that it started playing

Answer (score 0):

There are two seemingly similar functions that take a parameter `kSystemSoundID_Vibrate:`

1) `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`
2) `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`

Both the functions vibrate the `iPhone`. But when you use the first function on devices that don’t support vibration, it plays a beep sound. The second function on the other hand does nothing on unsupported devices. So if you are going to vibrate the device continuously, as a alert, common sense says, use function 2.

See also "iPhone Tutorial: Better way to check capabilities of iOS devices" article.

First, add the `AudioToolbox` framework (`AudioToolbox.framework`) to your target in Build Phases.

Then, header file to import:

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```